# Is it rude to remind an editor about a manuscript submission still waiting for an invitee after 2 months?

Tags: journals, peer-review

An original work has been submitted about 2 months ago to a journal thru their online interface and its status is still locked into "editor invited".
Would it be rude to remind them about this?

Oddly I've talked to the editor sometimes before sending my manuscript and she was always quick to reply, so I guess this status has to do with looking for another editor specialized in that field or for reviewers?
I fear this may cut down chances for paper to get published.

Thank you

Edit: I've seen that similar topic about 3 months but I believe it's different since it refers to a larger timeframe and a different, more advanced status in the peer-review process.

Comment: I am almost in a similar situation, but the status is 'with editor' since last 3 months. I don't know what to do. I have reminded the editorial office about it once.

Comment: Back in my day, and in my field (mathematics), I would never contact the journal about a paper until a year after submission...

Comment: Related: [Is it okay to inquire about the status of a paper when the online submission system shows no update three months after submission?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24162/is-it-okay-to-inquire-about-the-status-of-a-paper-when-the-online-submission-sys?rq=1).

Comment: No, it's not rude if it is a neutral question.

Comment: Look at my similar experience to find that there might be very more harsh situations, in view of delay, then this: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66219/what-should-i-do-as-my-submitted-paper-is-still-under-review-after-1-year

Comment: That's both sad and scary stuff, I never expected the world to revolve around me but neither for things to take long enough to impair and slow down my career, since I guess that's something obvious if an author's writing/elaborating/publishing speed is > or even worst >> than peer-reviewed journals' elaborating speed. It's like being outward-bound to reap results from 1 paper/year while being able yourself to publish 5 papers/year.