# my article has been evaluated since 17 months. what do you think about this situation?

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review, time-management, review-articles

I submitted my article to a journal on 12.01.2016. I asked many times about status of my paper. I have not received a reply from the editor even though my article has been evaluated since 17 months. what do you think about unethical situation?

Comment: Need not be unethical.  Maybe they're having a huge problem finding reviewers.

Comment: Have you contacted your editor solely? What about contacting the Editor-in-Chief? How is the  reputation of the journal? I would say you haven't provided enough information. I would suggest you give more details about the situation.

Comment: Similar case: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66219/what-should-i-do-as-my-submitted-paper-is-still-under-review-after-1-year

Comment: Journal is abstracted/indexed in Social Science Citation Index. Impact factor of journal is 0,5. I contacted editorial assistants that cover education journals. but I have not received a reply from the editor.

Comment: I wrote editor in chief too. but I have not received a reply from the editor.

Comment: The length of time may be highly dependent on the area.  You say "social science" and I have no knowledge of the times common for that area.

Answer (score 6):

If they're not answering emails, that is a very worrying sign. I would suggest sending an email to the editor (cc'ing the editor-in-chief and any other relevant people at the journal) saying that you are very concerned that they are not answering your emails, and that if they don't answer this email, you intend to withdraw the paper.

Then, if they don't answer the email within a reasonable time, send them another email withdrawing the paper.

Comment: "if they don't answer the email within a reasonable time": I think the best is to point out in the initial email which delay you are giving them, because standards for "reasonable time" tend to vary. Make it clear that this is about getting back in touch with you about some status update, not about finishing the review. E.g., "If I do not hear back from you within three weeks (or: by DATE) with information about the status of the submission, I will have to assume that something is wrong, and will have to withdraw the submission".

Answer (score 1):

While the course of action suggested by Peter is certainly correct and appropriate after a long wait, I don't think it's appropriate in your situation.

You said you have asked the editor many times and never heard back for 17 months (even if they have difficulty finding reviewers, they can at least let you know). That's **utterly unaccaptable** and never occurs with any good journal. Therefore, I suggest to without further delay **withdraw** your paper and **re-submit to a good journal** instead.