# Journal Paper Review (Computer Science) taking so long? How to proceed?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, computer-science, editors

I submitted a journal paper to Springer's SN Computer Science Journal.
[Below is the time line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VQbU.png)

1. 18th Nov, 2021 --> Manuscript Submitted
2. 15th Feb, 2022 --> Editor Decision (Major Revision)
3. 1st March, 2022--> Revised Manuscript submitted

Since then it shows "under review".

I have contacted the corresponding contact person several times and the editor as well. Either I do not get reply and if I receive a reply, it is always the same stating "under review and as soon as a decision is made, you will be notified and I have requested the editor to expedite the process". It has been more than a year since that revision had been submitted but I have not heard about the decision. Any leads what I shall do?
I am reluctant to withdraw it from here and submit elsewhere due to then again starting the long waiting time cycle.

Comment: Do any of the questions under the "Related" tab to the right answer your question? Especially https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/178056/should-i-withdraw-my-paper-because-review-is-taking-too-long and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66219/what-should-i-do-as-my-submitted-paper-is-still-under-review-after-1-year ?

Comment: I would love to hear an update. Gradually I am so fed up with the review process. Personally it only takes me 2 weeks to send them my reviews but then when it's me as author, it takes forever.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have no leverage to speed up the review, your only choices are to wait or to withdraw. You note, properly, that withdrawing is only likely to extend the time to publication.

Some things take time because of their nature or because of the difficulty of finding good reviewers.

I suggest patience. What you have heard from the editorial department is probably all you will or can hear until review is complete.

Hopefully you have other things to be working on.